# Finding Stable Most Stable configuration for Thomson Atom of 2 Electrons

Tags: atomic-physics

I have been having trouble solving a problem related to Thomson's model of the atom. Basically, if I assume the atom to be a sphere (of radius R) of uniformly distributed positive charge, and if I am being told that the most stable configuration is one where the two electrons lie along a diameter at a distance R/2 from the center, how do I show that this is the most stable configuration? Is there another configuration that is more stable? Thanks!